# Where can I find my iOS developer ID before publishing any app?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm almost ready to launch my first game on iOS and I want to add a link to *more games of the same studio*, so the App Store is opened and next games I release also appear there. To do so I need the developer ID, which is a number code, but I don't know where to get it.

For example, 296415947 is the DEV ID for Twitter Inc.:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/es/artist/twitter-inc./id296415947
```

I need mine but I have no apps published yet. Do you know where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in iTunes Connect:

`My Apps` --> `<name of your app>` --> `Versions`... then scroll down, the ID is written below the app icon in the section `General Information`.

[image]

Comment: Very nice.  Which app did you use to markup your screen shots?

Comment: I thought that this was the app id, not the dev id. So, if this is the dev id, I'm missing the APP ID. Where can I find it?

Comment: ah no sorry, that was my bad. I pointed you to the _App ID_... I just looked everywhere in _iTunes Connect_ and the _iOS Dev Center_ but wasn't able to find my actual Dev ID anywhere (the one that is displayed when you click "View more by this developer")... sorry, no idea where it can be found :/